# Angular Lazy loading - Issue with imported module having routes

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular12

In my application, I am using lazy loading and have 4 modules, each with its own routing. My module3 imports module2. When trying to route to localhost:xxxx/module3, it loads module2 components to display instead of displaying module 3 components.

I understand the issue is happening because of the imported module2 in module3. Any idea how we can tackle the situation where imported modules have their own routing?

Comment: If you have only one router link then what it means is it has to load components inside of it. But if you have a components that has a router link inside of it and it is being loaded with parent router link then angular knows it has to load your child routes inside of second router link.

Comment: You need to use children and second routerlink that's it.